# Why Rewriterule doens't work in my .htaccess file?

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling with this very rare problem.

I had the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

Rewriterule ^producto/(.+)/(.+) producto.php?id=$1&title=$2
Rewriterule ^pedidos/ pedidos.php

Rewriterule ^peliculas/(.+)/(.+) listado.php?tipo=1&gen=$1&pag=$2
Rewriterule ^musicales/(.+)/(.+) listado.php?tipo=2&gen=$1&pag=$2
Rewriterule ^blueray/(.+)/(.+) listado.php?tipo=4&gen=$1&pag=$2
Rewriterule ^condicionadas/(.+)/(.+) listado.php?tipo=5&gen=$1&pag=$2
Rewriterule ^series/(.+)/(.+) listado.php?tipo=3&gen=$1&pag=$2
```

And everything worked fine. When I wanted to change the fifth line:

```
Rewriterule ^pedidos/ pedidos.php
```

to this:

```
Rewriterule ^pedidos/(.+) pedidos.php?estado=$1
```

It did not work. No matter how much I change that line, it won't work.
BUT if I change any other line, the change works.
It's like there's a cached file but I restarted WAMP, I cleaned my computer and browsers with CCleaner, and nothing works.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add that before `RewriteEngine on`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Any explanation on why this works? I also found this and I'm worried about it: www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews

Comment: Yes. With MultiViews, Apache try to add .php if file does not exist without. With my option you disable it (it was activated before) so no any problem!